# How to sort number in character type in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep("1",4),
                 b=c("10","10","9","9"),
                 c=c("a","a_e","a","a_e"))

  a  b   c
1 1 10   a
2 1 10 a_e
3 1  9   a
4 1  9 a_e
```

Is there a clean way to sort the dataframe by a,b and c in ascending order?

Expected output (a,b and c **needs** to be character type):

```
expected <- data.frame(a=rep("1",4),
                 b=c("9","9","10","10"),
                 c=c("a","a_e","a","a_e"))

  a  b   c
1 1  9   a
2 1  9 a_e
3 1 10   a
4 1 10 a_e
```

In this case, arrange does not work:

```
> df%>%arrange(a,b,c)
  a  b   c
1 1 10   a
2 1 10 a_e
3 1  9   a
4 1  9 a_e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(across(a:b, as.numeric), c)
```

-output

```
  a  b   c
1 1  9   a
2 1  9 a_e
3 1 10   a
4 1 10 a_e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  arrange(str_order(a, numeric = TRUE),
          str_order(b, numeric = TRUE), c)


df %>%
  arrange(as.numeric(a), as.numeric(b), c)


 a  b   c
1 1 10   a
2 1 10 a_e
3 1  9   a
4 1  9 a_e
```

If there are any letters in a and b then use the first one otherwise use the second

Answer (score 1):

as a function for reproducibility on other data

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep("1",4),
                 b=c("10","10","9","9"),
                 c=c("a","a_e","a","a_e"))

myreorder <- function(x){
  require(tidyverse)
new_order <-  suppressWarnings({
x |> mutate(internal_rownumber_variable_=row_number(),
             across(.cols=everything(),
                    \(x)parse_number(as.character(x)))) |>
  arrange(!!!syms(setdiff(names(x),"internal_rownumber_variable_"))) |> pull(internal_rownumber_variable_)}) 
x[new_order,]
}
str(myreorder(df))
```